# Closure of open set

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space. $X$ is called H-closed if it is closed in all hausdorff spaces containing it.
My doubt is how can we prove that  closure of an open subset of an H-closed space is always H-closed.

Comment: What's an "h-closed space"?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: The easiest way to prove this is to prove first that a space $X$ is H-closed if and only if it has the following property: if $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$, there is a finite $\mathscr{U}_0\subseteq\mathscr{U}$ such that $\bigcup\mathscr{U}_0$ is dense in $X$. It is very easy to show that this property is inherited by the closures of open sets.

For convenience say that a family of sets *almost covers* $X$ if its union is dense in $X$.

Suppose that $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is H-closed, and that $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$ such that no finite subfamily of $\mathscr{U}$ almost covers $X$. For each $U\in\mathscr{U}$ let $V_U=X\setminus\operatorname{cl}U$, and let $\mathscr{V}=\{V_U:U\in\mathscr{U}\}$.

- Show that if $\mathscr{V}_0\subseteq\mathscr{V}$ is finite, then $\bigcap\mathscr{V}_0\ne\varnothing$.

Let $p$ be a new point not in $X$, and let $Y=\{p\}\cup X$.

- Show that if $\mathscr{B}=\big\{\{p\}\cup V:V\in\mathscr{V}\big\}$, then $\tau\cup\mathscr{B}$ is a base for a Hausdorff topology on $Y$.
- Get a contradiction by showing that $X$ is not closed in $Y$.

This shows that if $X$ is H-closed, then every open cover of $X$ has a finite subset that almost covers $X$. Now suppose that $X$ is not H-closed, and let $Y$ be a space containing $X$ as a non-closed subset. Let $p\in(\operatorname{cl}_YX)\setminus X$, and let $\mathscr{B}$ be the family of open nbhds of $p$ in $Y$.

- Use $\mathscr{B}$ and the ideas of the first part of the proof to construct an open cover of $X$ with no finite subset almost covering $X$.

Comment: Thank u sir for the hint given.

Comment: @Vinitha: You’re welcome.